# Why aren't questions migrated to related Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, asking-questions

According to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the moderators, questions which violate the FAQ should be migrated to related Stack Exchange sites and can even get downvoted.

When I'm surfing around [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), I'm seeing a lot of questions that maybe need to be migrated to the related sites. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762697/mysql-innodbinnodb-flush-method) is related to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com). Why wasn't it migrated to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)?

When I searched for "[Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Drupal)", I found there were a lot of Drupal-related questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and they even got upvoted. Why were they not migrated to [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com)?

**UPDATE**
Nowadays, what if I post a Drupal-related question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)?
Will it still be on-topic or will I be asked to flag it to migrate to Drupal Answers as the [Drupal-oriented Stack Exchange site](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) already exists?

Comment: First of all, it has to be off-topic on SO. Then somebody needs to actually see it. And of course questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated.

Comment: Why must they be migrated?

Comment: There's no point in the FAQ that says they should be migrated. Please cite where that statement comes from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not *should* be migrated. *Can* be migrated.

A lot of the questions you'll find on Stack Overflow that could be asked on another site are still on-topic on Stack Overflow and may have been posted before these other sites even existed.

There's not much point in just moving things around for the sake of moving things around. It's confusing for the askers, the answerers, and there are often nuances on the more specialized sites that make Stack Overflow questions poor fits for them. (For example, DBA.SE is into more complex questions and not just anything with SQL in it.)

In addition to all that, questions that are more than 60 days old cannot be migrated at all.

---

Far as your update goes... it depends a bit on the question. Stack Overflow is for *programming* problems. For Drupal this would be things like creating modules or modifying themes. (I think. I'm not actually familiar with Drupal.)

General Drupal usage questions such as module suggestions, troubleshooting, etc. would probably fare better over on Drupal.SE. Check out [their FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) for details on what's on-topic.

Like I said, I'm not very familiar with Drupal, but based on what I know, I think most development questions could land on either site.

Comment: Please see my update in the question.